# CSS @font-face src:url not accepting local hard-drive files

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm sure this must be a common question, but I have just spent the last hour trying to figure out how to craft a @font-face rule that references a font file on the local machine. I have copied examples from various websites, including stack overflow, and nothing is working.

I was just trying to start off with an ECM -- three files, all in one directory:

test.html:

```
<html>
      <head>
             <title>Document Title</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./test.css" />
      </head>

      <body>
          <p>Some text.</p>
      </body>
</html>
```

test.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: DreamOrphans;
    src: url(dreamorp.ttf) format ("truetype");
}
body {
    background: black;
    color: #80c0c0;
    font-family: DreamOrphans, "sans-serif", generic;
}
```

dreamorp.ttf (the font file)

When I open test.html in Firefox (40.something), it reverts to the default sans serif font.

If I change the font-face source to `local("Dream Orphans");` THEN it uses the font file installed under ~/.fonts -- so I know that the problem is simply that `src: url(...)` is failing to locate font files on the local hard drive.

I have tried:

```
url(dreamorp.ttf)
url("dreamorp.ttf'")
url("./dreamorp.ttf'")
url("/home/dlm/.fonts/dreamorp.ttf")
url("/home/dlm/Documents/web/fonts/dreamorp.ttf")
```

Nothing is working.

[Can relative paths be used for @font-face src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870699/can-relative-paths-be-used-for-font-face-src) suggests that single quotes around the path are not okay. I have tried double quotes and no quotes, no luck.

Per [@font-face does not work while fonts in subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832169/font-face-does-not-work-while-fonts-in-subfolder) I have copied the font file into the same directory as the css file. No luck.

If `url()` is not the right way to access local font files by relative path, then what is? Can I test my website locally, without involving a web server, and without having to `sed` all my font faces?

Comment: Can you add some more information there? Where does that `ttf` file live, relative to your HTML file? Are you loading this from file (file:///) or as served content (http://)?

Comment: All 3 files are in the same directory -- ls on the directory prints "dreamorp.ttf test.css test.html." Hence, definitely absolutely the font file is in the same location as the css. In Firefox, I am loading it by file://

Comment: resources loaded from file:/// have all kinds of crazy security restrictions, because it's super insecure otherwise. Run a localhost server and load your file as http:// instead and see what does for you (python: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, node: `npm installl -g http-server` and then `http-server` ever after, php: `php -S localhost:8000`, and a million other ways to run one)

Comment: OK, thanks, that explains it.

Answer (score 4):

url() uses a pathing system **relative** to that of the location of the CSS.

If your CSS is in

```
C:/home/etc/styles.css
```

Then url("myfont.ttf") will point to

```
C:/home/etc/myfont.ttf
```

Comment: As noted, my font file is in the same directory as the css. Yet url() fails to locate it. I am able to get Firefox to recognize the font *only* by using `local()` -- it does not even work to do `local("..."), url(...)` -- I'm quite perplexed.